# sequelize - inner join gives an error after added a foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have these 2 models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('services_prices', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    service_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'services',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    created_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    limit: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true
    }
  });
};
```

which is parent of this model: (services_user_prices can override services_prices )

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('services_user_prices', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true
    },
    created_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    currency: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    is_active: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: '0'
    },
    is_trial: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: '0'
    },
    start_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    end_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true
    },

    bundle_price_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'services_prices',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  });
};
```

when trying to join them i get an error:

EagerLoadingError: services_prices is not associated to services_user_prices!

```
 const result= await db.services_user_prices.findOne({
                where: { is_active: 1, user_id: 123 }, include:[{db.services_prices}]
            });
```

in the db services_user_prices has foreign key to services_prices table
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As complement of the above answer you need to add an identifier with `as:` on the association like this:

```
Model.belongsTo(models.ModelName, { foreignKey: 'your_key', as:'your_identifier' } )
```

Then when you do the include on the method you also call the identifier:

```
await db.services_user_prices.findOne({
    where: { is_active: 1, user_id: 123 }, 
    include:[{
        model: db.services_prices
        as: 'your_identifier'
    }]
});
```

If you don't define the `foreignKey` field, the `as` field will set the column name.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are using sequelize then you need to update your model because

by default, sequelize will be looking for foreign key starts with model name like

you have defined `bundle_price_id` as a foreign key for `services_prices`.

You need to change your column name to `services_price_id` then it will get fixed.

or if you want to use `bundle_price_id` you need to define it in your model relation as.

`Model.belongsTo(models.ModelName, { foreignKey: 'your_key'} )`

Please feel free if you need to ask anything else.

Comment: added this to the model file and still same error :  

 services_user_prices.associate = (models) => {
    services_user_prices.belongsTo(models.services_prices,{ foreignKey: 'bundle_price_id'} );
  }

Comment: Then I suggest changing bundle_price_id services_price_id so, If possible can you please share your model field so i can have look.